# How to tie weights to train multiple copies of the same model

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I need to implement the model below.

I have to do function A and function B to a sequence of data. 
Function A is implemented using a neural network and its output is input to the function B (Not a neural network, but implemented in Keras using Model functional API), and then the loss function is calculated at the output of the function B.

Input is L length vector of complex numbers. I need to input this to L copies of the same network (Sequential) in parallel. One network takes real and imaginary numbers of one element and outputs m real numbers.

So all the L networks will output m*L real numbers in total. The function B will take these m*L real numbers as input and calculate the output.

This is how I roughly planned,

```
model_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(L,))

function_A_model = Sequential()
function_A_model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
function_A_model.add(Dense(m))  # Output layer

function_A_inputs = [layers.Input(shape=(2,)) for i in range(L)]

function_A_outputs = []
for i in range(L):
    function_A_outputs = [function_A_outputs function_A_model(function_A_inputs[i]) ]

function_B_outputs = function_B(function_A_outputs)
```

I want to implement this as a larger Model using Model functional API, which will take model_inputs as above and output function_B_outputs.

My problems are,

1. I need to divide the model_inputs Input vector for L Input vectors of shape 2. How can I accomplish this in layers? or is it ok to have a vector of inputs?
2. How do I implement the function A in L copies of the same network (weights are tied)
3. How do I merge the m*L outputs to one Output vector so I can input it to function B?

Comment: try to set a seed and you can re-use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problems are,
>   I need to divide the model_inputs Input vector for L Input vectors of shape 2. How can I accomplish this in layers?

You can define a Lambda layer that slices the input. For instance:

```
example = Input(shape=(20,))
slice_0_4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :4])(example)
slice_4_16 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 4:16])(example)
slice_16_20 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 16:])(example)
```

> or is it ok to have a vector of inputs?

You can have a tensor of any shape you want including a shape that is (N, M).

For instance if you declare a model that is:

```
L = Input(shape=(20, 10,))
h1 = Dense(8)(L)
```

The dense layer above will be applied to all 20 time steps of the input. Dense layers share weights across time steps. So the same w matrix will be multiplied across all batches across all time steps, doing a 10x8 matrix multiplication.

> How do I implement the function A in L copies of the same network (weights are tied)

I'm not sure I follow your question. You can have the top level model split its input and call a sub model with a slice of the input; or you can have a model that performs the same set of operations on a matrix that includes extra dimensions.

> How do I merge the m*L outputs to one Output vector so I can input it to function B?

You can use the keras `Concatenate` layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the first part and the last part answers my question. My problem is I have to input these slices into the same model, or parallel copies of the same model (Sequential) with same weights so that I can take the output and concatenate together to input to the next block, function B.